# How to match elements containing string from BeautifulSoup list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the input.html belowI

**Input.html**
https://jsfiddle.net/f86q7ubm/

And I'm trying to match all elements within list `allList` with size=5, but when I run the following code, the matching has no values inside.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fp = open("file.html", "rb")                 
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp,"html5lib")

allList = soup.find_all(True)

matching = [s for s in allList if 'size="5"' in s]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may(should) be a better way to this, but you can just do `str(s)`. You were trying to do a match in a non-string object:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fp = open("file.html", "rb")                 
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp,"html5lib")

allList = soup.find_all(True)

matching = [s for s in allList if 'size="5"' in str(s)]
```

Not sure if this is what you want, but a better way could be:

```
allList = soup.find_all("font", {"size": "5"}) # you already have the matching elements here
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure why I see elements with size different to 5 within matching when  I run `[s for s in allList if 'size="5"' in str(s)] `

Comment: Because it matches text inside the elements which can have other nested elements. So there can be two <font> elements one with size 5 and the other with size 3 inside a <div> element. Does that help ?

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("font", {'size': 5}):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
TEXT S 5 MORE TEXT
TEXT S 5 MORE TEXT
TEXT S 5 MORE TEXT
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't seen the option to filter like you did `"font {...}"` I think I need to check a more complete user guide abot this bs module.